# IBM WAS 8.5.5 ND configurations that need to restart the environment

Tags: websphere, was

I have applied some WAS configuration but I don´t know in which cases I have to restart it.

I want to know in which cases I have to restart the entire environment. I know when JNDI and dataq sources are configured the restart is needed but no more.

Thank you

Comment: The safest choice is to always restart the server/cluster you made a changes. In this way you dont have to think which change will be active and which not. I know its a bit overkill but I consider it a best practice in case of traditional WAS.